# jQuery 'document', 'body' and 'html' selectors not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone

I need to run a function when you click anywhere on the page. Initially I used this:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    // stuff to happen
});
```

This works perfectly in my android phone and in firefox, but doesnt work on iPhones. Ive tried changing 'html' to 'body' and 'document' but still no luck.

Is there a proper iPhone way to use anything as a selector? I guess I could use '*' but I dont want the overhead as this is a mobile optimised site. Thanks

Comment: I've had similar issues with IE before. Instead of binding to $('html').click(), try binding to $('body').click() or other elements you might be able to test with.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but it's often useful to add a full-page empty div under your menu, and then apply the click to that. You have a bit more control over things and don't have to deal with as many propagation issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$('body').click(function() { …` ?