# On click function without selector / anything as selector?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible with jQuery to have an onclick function without any selector? So instead of this:

```
$('#div').click(function() {
```

You would have this:

```
$(anything).click(function() {
```

Ive tried using html and body as the selector. This works fine except on iPhones, so is there a standard way of saying 'anything' as a selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$('*').click(function() {});
```

or better delegate it back to the body

```
$('body').delegate('*', 'click', function() {});
```

---

**as Lonesomeday Suggested as an alternative**

```
$(document).click(function() {});
```

Comment: I second that motion -- I don't like the first form, potentially (with a large document tree) it would be problematic.

Comment: Since you're using `*`, `delegate` isn't actually very helpful. It just adds overhead.

Comment: @lonesomeday ....  `delegate()` would be better than `$('*').click()` as it only actually binds an event handler to the body and not to each individual element in the DOM.  With that in mind where would the extra overhead be seen.

Comment: @JohnHartsock The overhead is compared to `$('body').click`, or, as I've suggested, `$(document).click`.

Comment: @lonesomeday I'd assume it'd be faster to pass the reference to the actual `DOM` element instead of passing a selector for jQuery to search...

Comment: looks like it is not such a big deal to pass into the `ctor` `$('body')` as the init method will automatically assign `$[0] = document.body` - though passing a reference to the DOM element is ideal...

Comment: Ive asked the question more specifically here in case there is a solution that doesn't use *. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740930/jquery-document-body-and-html-selectors-not-working-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether it will work on iPhones, but you should be able to avoid the universal selector by simply detecting the click on `document`.

```
$(document).click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can bind the `click` event to *every* element using:

```
$('*').click(function(){...});
```

This will cause a lot of duplication of event handlers

Instead, you could use:

```
$(window).click(function(){});
-or-
$(document).click(function(){});
```

to just listen for a click anywhere.

Alternatively, if you *must* use element selectors, you could try:

```
$('body').delegate('*', 'click', function(){...});
```